# Akka Actors And Schedulers

Tags: akka

Is the following example a classical anti pattern when it comes to Scheduling messages?

```
class MyActor extends Actor {

  private val scheduler = context.system.scheduler.schedule(3.seconds, 3.seconds, self, Tick)

  def receive = {
    case Tick => processMessage(....)
  }
}
```

Why should I stay away from using local schedulers?

Comment: One problem as I already see is that testing this Actor becomes difficult. Assume if I have quite a bit of logic inside this actor, then I'm doomed, but other than that is this considered an anti pattern? What do you guys think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll try to summarise why you shouldn't use scheduler as a default pattern.

1. If you submit more tasks than the number of task you process your JVM could run out of memory or your tasks could be delayed.
2. Actor scheduler is not persistent, so if for example at 17:50 you scheduled a Tick message to be sent in 10 minutes, but due to some exception, your actor was restarted by supervisor 17:53 actor as part of default supervision policy, as the result your scheduled task will be delayed for 3 minutes... To sole this issue you can use persistent actor which will replay all scheduled events and reschedule it if event time is greater then current time you schedule period will be delta of those two timestamps.
3. Akka scheduler based on `HashedWheeltimer` which is best for scheduling short periods

In our project we are using "Actor per Request" pattern we are sending the message to other actor from the "request actor" and then are setting `context.setReceiveTimeout(x seconds)`. if we did not receive any response withing x seconds we consider this message as lost and apply our logic according to which pattern are we using "at least once" or "at most once" delivery.